# jQuery select ID from comma separated list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple one liner I can use to select the nth element from a comma separated list in jQuery?

For example if I have:
var eg = "a,b,c,d";

How can I select element c?

Comment: tip: enclose all code within backticks " ` " so it appears like this: `var eg = "a,b,c,d";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var eg = "a,b,c,d";
eg.split(",")[2];
```

Comment: ha! I just noticed the OP tagged it as jQuery. Opps. Bring on the downvotes.

Comment: jQuery version, for fun: `jQuery.split = function(s, d){return s.split(d)}` then `$.split("a,b,c,d", ",")[2]`

Comment: @Kyle—cool! More code to just call the function than write the expression!